# Abstract the (duplicate?) behavior between "sort" and "replace"

Tags: strings, lisp, common-lisp

I have written these two functions that have a similar process.  The first is meant to "split" a string on a given character and the second is meant to "replace-all" instances of a character in a given string.  The behavior between the two seems very similar - can you think of a good way to abstract that behavior into a third, reusable, function?  (which could be executed by calling, for example, (where-found sought-letter searchee-string thing-to-do)).

```
(defun split (separator splittee)
  (let ((next-index (position separator splittee)))
    (if next-index
      (cons (subseq splittee 0 next-index) (split separator (subseq splittee (1+ next-index))))
      (list splittee))))

(defun replace-all (replacand replacee replacor)
  (let ((next-index (position replacand replacee)))
    (if next-index
      (concatenate 'string (subseq replacee 0 next-index) replacor (replace-all replacand (subseq replacee (1+ next-index)) replacor))
      replacee)))
```

What do you think?  Is this better than the original code, or is it too complicated?

```
(defun where-found (sought-letter the-string to-do-onroute to-do-on-leaf)
  (let ((next-index (position sought-letter the-string)))
    (if next-index
      (apply to-do-onroute
         (list (subseq the-string 0 next-index) 
           (subseq the-string (1+ next-index))))
      (apply to-do-on-leaf (list the-string))))) 

(defun split (separator splittee)
  (where-found separator splittee 
           (lambda (pre-string post-string) (cons pre-string (split separator post-string))) 
           (lambda (leaf-string) (list leaf-string))))

(defun replace-all (to-be-replaced-string the-patient-string the-replacement-string)
  (where-found to-be-replaced-string the-patient-string 
           (lambda (pre-string post-string) 
         (format t "pre: ~a post: ~a the-replacement-string: ~a ~%" pre-string post-string the-replacement-string) 
         (concatenate 'string pre-string the-replacement-string (replace-all to-be-replaced-string post-string the-replacement-string)))
           (lambda (leaf-string) leaf-string)))

(format t "the cat is here: ~a ~%" (replace-all #\Space "the cat is here" ""))
(format t "the cat is here: ~a ~%" (split #\Space "the cat is here"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the later versions are unnecessarily complicated and verbose.

My first idea was to just concatenate the splitted list parts in replace-all – for you can do `(concatenate 'string seqs ... )` – but that may not be very efficient.

You can use map or loop for replace-all. This map version works for lists too:

```
(defun replace-all (seq from to)
  (map (type-of seq) (lambda (char) (if (equal from char) to char)) seq))
```

Naming things clearly can sometimes be hard, and I think sometimes being terse helps readability more than being too-explicit-and-specific. That if statement above could need some better naming of things...

There is an utility library called [split-sequence](http://www.cliki.net/SPLIT-SEQUENCE), that has many useful options, like

- remove empty subsequences
- only split count times
- return the index position (useful for further processing)

I'm still learning Lisp, so you may want to hear see other answers also.

Comment: That does look pretty nice and simple.  What would you do for split?